# If $|f(x,y)|\le C_1(y)x^2$ and $|f(x,y)|\le C_2(x)y^2$, is it true that $|f|\le Cx^2y^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Question: Given that $f(x,y):B(0,1)\mapsto\mathbb R$ and there exists real functions $C_1(y):(-1,1)$ and $C_2(x):(-1,1)$ such that
$$|f(x,y)|\le C_1(y)x^2$$
$$|f(x,y)|\le C_2(x)y^2$$
for all $(x,y)\in B(0,1)$, where $B(0,1)$ is the open unit ball on $\mathbb R^2$. Then, is it true that there exists constant $C>0$ such that $$|f(x,y)|\le Cx^2y^2$$ ?

---

The answer is yes if the given conditions are that $|f(x,y)|=C_1(y)x^2$ and $|f(x,y)|=C_2(x)y^2$. We would have
$$\begin{align}
C_1(y)x^2&=C_2(x)y^2 \\
\frac{C_1(y)}{y^2} &=\frac{C_2(x)}{x^2}\qquad x,y\ne 0\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\frac{C_1(y)}{y^2}=\frac{C_2(x)}{x^2}=\text{constant}$. It follows immediately that $f(x,y)=\text{constant}\cdot x^2y^2$. However, if the given conditions are inequalities, no similar proofs can be reproduced.

---

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what does the notation $C_1(y):(-1,1)$ mean???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $f(x,y)=\min\{x^2,y^2\}$? Consider $f(x,x)$. How would this behave if your claim was true?